# Xcode 6 with Xcode 5 projects. ViewController view size is not correct

Tags: xcode6

I've just tried to do this simple operation.

- Open an Xcode 5 project with Xcode 6
- Check "use size classes"
- Create a new controller in you storyboard and set it as Root
- In the viewDidLoad method print the view size

I get always the same size of 320 x 568 even if I'm testing on the iPhone6 or 6+ simulator. 
Why?! Is this a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you must insert launchimage 5.5 4.7 into project